# Put brackets around filename for Excel formula

Tags: java, string, swing, apache-poi

My project is based on Apache POI.I'm trying to use a formula on a cell.
My formula is as follows.

```
sheet7.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellFormula("+'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\[Test.xlsx]Average_Graph'!A2");
```

Im using a JFileChooser, which allows users to select the file. Therefore the filepath will be changed every time the program is used.

From the JFileChooser, I'm getting a filepath as follows.

```
 String filepath= "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Sheet.xlsx"`
```

In order to work the formula correctly, the filepath should be in following format.

```
"C:\\Users\\Desktop[Sheet.xlsx]"
```

How Can I Change the string which I'm getting from the JFileCHooser to run the formula correctly?

Comment: In your java program there is a `String` with wrong escapes. Is that actually in the source code like this?

Comment: What do you mean "as follows"? You want to **insert** the brackets? Or only get the filename?

Comment: Also, is the result correct, without a `"\\"` before the `"["`?

Comment: How do you produce the `String` value?

Comment: No. I've posted the string that way for the simplicity.

Comment: @LSH94 then try correct the example you have posted and also try to include so more code. It is not really clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @deHaar i get the string from JFileChooser.

Comment: @cricket_007 I need to add [ ] for the file name and add another \ for the file path.

Comment: nobody will help you if you don't show every needed info

Comment: @LSH94 so you want the `String` to be changed after having got it by `JFileChooser`? Do you want those brackets inserted or do you want the file name only?

Comment: @LSH94 please share your code. Otherwise having people try to speculate on what you're attempting to do and providing information in the way of comments is not enough.

Comment: `JFileChoser` gives you a `File` object, not a String, AFAIK

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `JFileChooser`, you have a `File` object, not just a `String`

And you **should** use the `File` or `Paths` API anyway to be OS independent

```
File f = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
String path = f.getParent();
String name = f.getName();

String newFormat = String.format("%s[%s]", path, name);
```

Comment: Given that the OP really does want to achieve the pattern they described, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is clear and concise, and what I think is being requested for.

Comment: @cricket_007 The code you gave about did the work. But for another part, I need to change it to get the output as 
C:\\Users\\Desktop\\[Sheet.xlsx]
Please help.

Comment: What difficulties are you having adding the last slash? Java isn't storing that internally, it only displays it as an escape character, so I don't understand the problem. More specifically, don't you think it's simply `"%s\\[%s]"` as the format?

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it you get the path as a String from a file chooser. So in your example you can do:

```
   String filepath= "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Sheet.xlsx"
   Path path = Paths.get(filepath);
   String result=path.getParent()+"["+path.getFileName()+"]";
```

And result will be your new string containing the file surrounded by braces

Or another solution would be using a File

```
  File f=new File(filepath);
  String result=f.getParent()+"["+f.getName()+"]";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just split parent directonary name and file name and putting the chars "[" and "]" around the file name:

```
    File select = fileC.getSelectedFile();
    String filepath = select.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()+"["+select.getName()+"]";
```

*EDIT i understood the question wrong so i thought about the false problem;

Comment: Why would he need 2 file separators? He probably has two in the initial string for escape reasons

Comment: Please read the comments, there he says "i get the string from JFileChooser. ". Thus he'd need a more flexible solution.