# Put Brackets around filename

Tags: java, string, apache-poi

**This is a correction of my previous question** [Put brackets around filename for Excel formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51999652/put-brackets-around-filename-for-excel-formula/51999820#51999820)

My project is based on Apache POI.I'm trying to use a formula on a cell.
My formula is as follows.

```
sheet7.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellFormula("+'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\[Test.xlsx]Average_Graph'!A2");
```

Im using a JFileChooser, which allows users to select the file. Therefore the filepath will be changed every time the program is used.

From the JFileChooser, I'm getting a filepath as follows.

```
 String filepath= "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Sheet.xlsx"`
```

In order to work the formula correctly, the filepath should be in following format.

```
"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\[Sheet.xlsx]"
```

How Can I Change the string which I'm getting from the JFileCHooser to run the formula correctly?

In previous question, I mistakenly typed **C:\Users\Desktop[Sheet.xlsx]** instead of **C:\Users\Desktop\[Sheet.xlsx]**
The answers gave me the output which i've mentioned. But I need the Output as `C:\Users\Desktop\[Sheet.xlsx]`

Please help.

Comment: uh, need to amend the answers a bit and you are good to go i supose....

Comment: `String result=path.getParent()+File.separator+"["+path.getFileName()+"]";`, see [separators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5972020/4648586).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve this by directly altering the file path, you may use `String#replaceAll`:

```
String filepath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Sheet.xlsx";
filepath = filepath.replaceAll("(?<=\\\\)([^\\\\]+)$", "[$1]");
System.out.println(filepath);

C:\Users\Desktop\[Sheet.xlsx]
```

### Demo

Comment: That Worked. Thanks

Comment: How to get "\\" instead of "\" as the output?

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Comment: I'm Using Apache POI for a project based on excel file. In that, I need to use a formula with a file path. It only runs if the file path is something like C:\\Users\\Desktop\\[Sheet.xlsx]. Not working with only one backslash. Please help.

Comment: You should open a new question.  This is different from what you asked, and would invalidate the two answers given here already.

Comment: Posted a new question. If you know the answer, Please help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050242/change-a-string-put-brackets-around-file-name-and-get-two-backslashes

Answer (score 1):

File names won't have \backslashes  in them, so we can assume that our filename begins after the last backslash and ends at the end of the string.

We can use this:

```
String filepath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Sheet.xlsx";
String dir = filepath.substring(0, filepath.lastIndexOf("\\"+1));
String filename = filepath.substring(filepath.lastIndexOf("\\"+1));

filepath = dir + "[" + filename + "]";
```

Or a shorter version:

```
String filepath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Sheet.xlsx";
filepath =  filepath.substring(0, filepath.lastIndexOf("\\"+1)) +
            "[" + filepath.substring(filepath.lastIndexOf("\\"+1)) + "]";
```